# Dealing with product types on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm really confused about how to properly get the product type in Woocommerce if I try to get it this way:

```
$product->get_type();
```

It always returns `simple` even if the product is variable, I then tried the following:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($this->product->get_id(), 'product_type');
$product_type = (!empty($terms)) ? sanitize_title(current($terms)->name) : 'simple';
```

As you can see from the code above, it gets the taxonomy `product_type` of the product and returns the taxonomy name if it exists, otherwise, it returns `simple`.

However it still returns `simple` even if the product is variable, I don't know what to do now, as Im getting the product object from a parameter of a woocommerce hook I don't know what type of product it is, I need to make this verification.

How to appropriately get the type of product in woocommerce?

### UPDATE

As requested I will add the full code Im using, so you have a better context on what Im trying to achieve.

Basically I want to show a meta field as a column in the order line items admin edit screen.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'ebani_add_cost_price_column_order_value_admin_edit', 10, 3);
function ebani_add_cost_price_column_order_value_admin_edit( $product, $item, $item_id ) {
    
    $order = $item->get_order();
    
    ?>
    <td class="item_cost_price" width="1%" data-sort-value="<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_item_subtotal( $item, false, true ) ); ?>">
        <div class="view">
            <?php
            if( ! is_null( $product ) ){
                
                //The right way to get the product type
                $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_type' );
                $product_type = ( !empty( $terms ) ) ? sanitize_title( current( $terms )->name ) : 'simple';
                echo $product_type;
                if( $product_type == 'variable' ) {
                    $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
                    echo wc_price( get_post_meta( $variation_id, 'variation_cost', true ), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                }elseif( $product_type == 'simple' ) {
                    echo wc_price( get_post_meta( $item->get_product_id(), 'cost_price', true ), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                }else{
                    echo "No aplica";
                }
            } else {
                echo 'No aplica';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand the use of `get_the_terms`. [`get_type()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#139-149) should suffice.

```php
// Add header
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers( $order ) {
    echo '<th class="line_mytitle sortable" data-sort="your-sort-option">My Title</th>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 10, 1 );

//Add content
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $product, $item, $item_id ) {
    $order = $item->get_order();

    ?>
    <td class="item_cost_price" width="1%" data-sort-value="<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_item_subtotal( $item, false, true ) ); ?>">
        <div class="view">
            <?php
            if( ! is_null( $product ) ) {
                // Get product type
                $product_type = $product->get_type();

                echo 'product type = ' . $product_type . '<br>';

                if( $product_type == 'variation' ) {
                    $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
                    echo wc_price( get_post_meta( $variation_id, 'variation_cost', true ), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                } elseif( $product_type == 'simple' ) {
                    echo wc_price( get_post_meta( $item->get_product_id(), 'cost_price', true ), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                } else {
                    echo "No aplica";
                }
            } else {
                echo 'No aplica';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3 );
```